# Count rows grouped by a column when another column is the same

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by

In the following table I would like to count the number of people that submitted at least one solution to a problem.

This is the table:

```
id user_name problem_name
1  john      sums
2  john      trees
3  john      sums
4  martin    sums
5  martin    trees
6  martin    trees
7  jim       trees
```

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
sums 2
trees 3
```

I would group by `problem_name`, but only when the `user_name` column is the same. I have no idea how to write this in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select problem_name, count(distinct user_name) as count
from mytable
group by problem_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_2.problem_name, count(*) from
       (select user_name, problem_name
       from table_1
       group by user_name, problem_name) as table_2
       group by problem_name
```

I think using a subquery is faster than use `distinct` if you have many rows, but I'm not sure.